# Understanding red X over Python Toolbox icon

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, python-toolbox, pythonwin

I've been updating a toolbox script, and I keep getting barred from accessing the script through ArcCatalog:

[image]

I make my updates on pythonWin, then check its validity in ArcMap. I've tried restarting Arc, pythonwin, and my computer, but to no avail. I have ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop with an Advanced license.

Answer (score 3):

That red cross is not about licensing.  I think you have a syntax error in your `*.pyt`.

In the Catalog window of ArcMap right-click on the `*.pyt` and I think you'll see an option for `Check Syntax`.